# PHP-Javascript Encrypt and Decrypt using the same secret key

Tags: php, javascript, encryption

I am working on an application who's front end is in javascript (backbone) and backend in codeigniter(php). I want a way where I can encrypt a message in backend using a secret key and decrypt that message from javascript using same secret key. Basically I need this flow for user authentication.

Its turning out to be a hard luck as I am not able to find such a combination over internet. What way can be used for this workflow?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't SSL/TLS-based HTTP what you are looking for? If the JavaScript part communicates with your PHP-API via HTTPS, then the messages are encrypted.

Comment: There is no real secure decryption on the client side. Everyone may look at the algorithm and keys ...

Comment: And how would you transfer this secret key to the client?

Comment: fab, the key will be constant at server(php) and client(js) side.

Comment: That means anyone with the JavaScript has the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using HTTPS is pretty much the only answer that makes sense.  Relying on Javascript cryptography is bad because malicious users can do all sorts of nasty stuff to inject scripts to make your front end instead send passwords out in plaintext, or send them to a server controlled by the attackers.

HTTPS and SSL/TLS has it's problems, but it is the standard mechanism for securing web application communication channels.  It has been reviewed extensively by experts in the field, and has been secured against various failure modes and attack scenarios.

For instance: It sounds like in your comment that you are going to use a single static key for your encryption.  Since you need to send the key to the client, how are you going to do this securely?  What prevents a user from getting the key legitimately by visiting your login page, then using it to decrypt the communications of any other users? What about when enough messages have been sent with one key, what is your mechanism for moving to a new key?

These sorts of scenarios are covered by HTTPS.  You might have to pay a few bucks for a certificate if you are doing something "real" with your webapp (and it really is just a few bucks these days), but it is really the way to go.